# Move Symmetrically two groups in kineticjs

Tags: line, kineticjs

I have two groups that are displayed symmetrically, in the stage, each one contains a line, my requirement is when i move a group the other group moves symmetrically to the first group.

this is the code

```
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 900,
height: 450
});
mouse = stage.getMousePosition();
layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.on("mousedown", function () { 
    traitGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x:  mouse.x,
    y: mouse.y,

    draggable: true
    });
    traitGroupMir = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: stage.getWidth()-mouse.x,
    y: mouse.y,

    draggable:true
    }); 
    layer.add(traitGroup);
    layer.add(traitGroupMir);

    line = new Kinetic.Line({
    points: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    stroke: "red",
    strokeWidth: 5,
    draggable: false
    });
    lineMirr = new Kinetic.Line({
              points: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              stroke: "red",
      strokeWidth: 5,
      draggable: false
    });
    traitGroup.add(line);
    traitGroupMir.add(lineMirr);


    traitGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
    this.moveToTop();
    });
    traitGroupMir.on('dragstart', function() {
    this.moveToTop();
    });
traitGroup.on('dragmove', function() {
    traitGroupMir.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
    traitGroupMir.setY(this.getY());
});
traitGroupMir.on('dragmove', function() {
traitGroup.setX(stage.getWidth()-this.getX());
    traitGroup.setY(this.getY());
 });
    stage.add(layer);
 });
```

Is there an error in the code?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do :-)  I did notice that your line points are all zero (that means each line draws nothing).

Comment: I like to move one line symetrically to another, for example when i move traitGroup, the traitGroupMir group will move as follow traitGroupMir.setX(stage.getWidth()-traiGroup.getX());